# openid: create claim based authorization attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, single-sign-on, openid, claims-based-identity

I have implemented `SSO` to my api (`web-api 2`) and it's validating correctly the token. But now I have to add a claim based authorization attribute. In the access token I have:

```
 "MyClaim.Read.All": "true"
```

And I would like to achieve something like:

```
[ClaimAuthorizationAttribute("MyClaim.Read.All")]
public sealed class MerchantProfileController : ApiController
```

So that if the token doesn't contain this claim, I would give a `401` error.

How to achieve this, so I can use this attribute to any controller I want with any claim?

Answer (score 0):

So I've created an authorization attribute:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public sealed class ClaimAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the claim to check in the web token
        /// </summary>
        public string Claim { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionContext));
            }

            var decoder = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = (JwtSecurityToken)decoder.ReadToken(actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter);

            return token.Claims.Any(c => c.Type.Equals(this.Claim) && c.Value.Equals("True", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
    }
```

And here is applied to a controller:

```
[ClaimAuthorization(Claim = "MyClaim.Read.All")]
```