# secure webapi with a valid JWT based on claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, jwt, claims-based-identity

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42007131/openid-create-claim-based-authorization-attribute) is how I've created an claim based authorization attribute. But I have some doubts about how this work.

Given the code from my startup class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        }

        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authentication:Authority"],
            RequiredScopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authentication:Scopes"].Split(' ').ToList(),
            PreserveAccessToken = true
        });
    }
```

I was expecting that if I have this attribute to my controller and I send an invalid token(invalid signature) the request will be automatically rejected as unauthorized, but the code from the attribute is executed.

Shouldn't `OWIN` validate the token first?

How to make sure that the token is valid (valid stricture, signature, not expired, etc) and only after validate the claims?

Comment: from your previous question: if you change the return statement  `return token.Claims.Any` with `return token.Claims.All` you still getting this error?

Comment: @Tinwor That would require that _all_ the claims on the token were identical, rather than just checking if any single one of them matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is within your linked question in your `ClaimAuthorizationAttribute` - it doesn't ever call `base.IsAuthorized()`, thus bypassing the built in protection mechanisms offered by `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Instead of just returning here after seeing whether or not the claim is present:

```
return token.Claims.Any(c => c.Type.Equals(this.Claim) && c.Value.Equals("True", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

You should instead carry on with making sure that the base class is satisfied, and thus the token itself is valid, too:

```
var claimValid = token.Claims.Any(c => c.Type.Equals(this.Claim) && c.Value.Equals("True", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
if (claimValid)
    return base.IsAuthorized();
else
    return false;
```

Comment: I was thinking at this option but then I've looked at the source code (https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) I saw that this does not validate the token...

Comment: @Buda Not directly, but it does check if the user is authenticated, which they won't be if they don't have a valid token